# Cannot Clear-Reset Picker in viewModel xamarin

Tags: xamarin.forms

I am trying to clear a form that has few textboxes and also a picker control.
I have this button that when the user presses it ,it should clear the form.
Whatever I do I seem to get an error

I have done the following

- xaml: I have bound the picker to a selectedIndex property
- ViewModel:Added a property and a method as follows

  ```
  private int selectedIndex;
  public int SelectedIndex
  {
      get { return selectedIndex; }
      set { SetProperty(ref selectedIndex, value); }
  }

  private void ResetForm()
  {
      SelectedIndex = -1;
  }
  ```

When I execute the code it crashes.

What is the way to reset the picker in the viewModel?

many thanks

Comment: The code seems to be ok, what is the crash log? Does crash when you run it or when you're trying to set the SelectedIndex? Could show us your xaml file? maybe there is something wrong. If you're not getting a crash log, try to turn on system.exceptions.

Comment: Hi,Created a dummy project and it works ,need to look better at the production code